# How to get a random value from dictionary and print just the key?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to code a word guessing game in the following and I get a type error. How to fix it? Thanks!

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits":"watermelon", "buildings": "apartment", "mammal": "horse", "occupation": "fireman"}


def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(Dictionary.items())
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    blank = []
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank.append("_")
    print("".join(blank))
    return chosen_word
```

Comment: You have defined `def choose_word():` but in the end, you are trying to call `chosen_word` so it is a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've a typo at your last line of the snippet, I don't think fixing it will work. So try this one.

```py
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": "papaya", "buildings": "apartment", "mammal": "horse"}


def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))
    print("Hint: " + hint)

choose_word()
```

Here `Dictionary.items()` returns tuple of key-value pairs. With `random.choice()` we're choosing one such tuple. And then we're unpacking the corresponding key-value to `hint` and `chosen_word` respectively.

Comment: @JD yes I made a typo and corrected it, and it still has an error. But @ Jishan your solution helps! Thanks!